# Is there a method to updating value with unknown sub key in Python 3 Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working with dictionary structure of Python 3 and I want to some change in a dictionary with desired and changeable key.

For instance, let's create a dictionary as follow:

```
 myDict = {
        'foo': {
            'a':12,
            'b':14
        },
        'bar': {
            'c':12,
            'b':14
        },
        'moo': {
            'a':12,
            'd':14
        },
     }
```

In this point, a key that is unknown will have and will used to find desired data path.
So, if received key is "myDict.foo.a", I must change value of "a" variable of foo, or if the key is "myDict.moo.a", I will change value of "a" variable of moo. As in this example, the key to use is unknown and I have a value that will put to the identified key (data path).

Under these conditions, how to change dictionary value with unknown key (data path).

To better explain, I described a dysfunctional code snippet about the solve of this question:

```
dictionary = init_dic()                  # initialization step for dictionary
desired_value = 1                        # a variable to use for change operation in dictionary
received_key = get_key()                 # receive unknown key group (exp: myDict.foo.a)
dictionary[received_key] = desire_value  # The question of this topic
```

Thank you for reading, have a good day!

Comment: could you show as a concrete example where you show the value of the key and how you would insert a value for that key?

Comment: I think I have already shown it in the above non-functional code.

Answer (score 0):

For the question I asked, I found a solution like below using "exec".

```
myDict = {}
myDict["myDict"] = { 'foo': { 'a':12, 'b':14 }, 'bar': { 'c':12, 'b':14 }, 'moo': { 'a':12, 'd':14 }, }

print(myDict)
```

> {'myDict': {'foo': {'a': 12, 'b': 14}, 'bar': {'c': 12, 'b': 14},
>   'moo': {'a': 12, 'd': 14}}}

```
data_path = "myDict.foo.a"
desired_value = 1

exec_string = "myDict"
for path in data_path.split("."):
    exec_string += "[\"{}\"]".format(path)
exec_string += " = {}".format(desired_value)

exec(exec_string)

print(myDict)
```

> {'myDict': {'foo': {'a': 1, 'b': 14}, 'bar': {'c': 12, 'b': 14},
>   'moo': {'a': 12, 'd': 14}}}

This perspective is required some control steps but, for me, enough for now. For instance, incoming sub data path can be unwanted command such as open("file.txt","w"). Therefore a control mechanism is required.

If you have different suggestion as solution, could you write here?